# SQL Server : join tables with many conditions

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-update

I have two tables:

- table of items. Each item has a type (string) and name.

[image: Table 1 - Items]

- table of connections between items. Side-A and Side-B Contain keys from table 1. The sides has meaning - **it is matter** if an item is on side A or side B.

[image: Table 2 - Connections]

We can assume that every item of Type 1 (in yellow) must have **at least one connection** with an item of Type 2 (green), while the Type-1-item is in **side A** and the Type-2-item is in **side B**. There can be also type 2 in side A and type 1 in side B but we can ignore them. I'm interesting **only** in items of **Type 1** that has **Side B of type 2**. In my example - it's the rows I marked with red arrows.

Now, I need to `UPDATE` (with T-SQL script) the names of every item of type-1, with the name of the **first** item of type-2 that is related to it in side B.
In my example - item 1 will get the name of item 3 (although it has a connection to item 6 as well) and item 2 will get the name of item 3.

I'm having troubles with this script, I'll be glad to get help...

Comment: What have you tried so far? First write the select then worry about the update.

Comment: I couldn't even succeed to complete the select script. I'm better in C#, not SQL...

Comment: Please add the relevant tables ddl+dml for the sample data so that we can try to work on it. don't make us do the boring stuff also... :-)

Comment: Have you installed SQL Server  Management Studio? That is a development tool for SQL Server that lets you write queries. First do that. If yoo are more familiar with C# you might prefer LINQ instead. Have you considered LINQ?

Comment: You need to use a sub-query in your update.  Your sub-query will start with `SELECT TOP 1`.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid I must create SQL script, not LINQ. I do have SQL Server Management Studio.

Comment: @TabAlleman I tried this but I guess something is missing because now I get every item of type-1 in side A with EVERY item on side B (include items that does not have connection with it at all). I guess I'm missing something. Plus I don't know how to select only type-2 on side B.

Comment: @ZoharPeled I can't, the tables I put here are not my real tables and I can't put here my real tables (they are hugh and also belong to my work...)

Comment: @TamarG if you post your script with the subquery, I'll be glad to help you debug it.

Comment: First step: `select IA.* from Items IA`. second step: `select IA.* from Items IA inner join Connections C on IA.Key = C.Side_A_Key` third step: `select IA.* from Items IA inner join Connections C on IA.Key = C.Side_A_Key inner join Items IB on IB.Key = C.Side_B_Key`. Hows that working out for you?

Comment: @TamarG You don't have to post the actual tables, just the script to create the sample data you posted as pictures. nobody expects you to post actual data from your workplace, most of us understands the need for keeping the business secrets...

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid great! now I need to get only the *first result* for every type-1-item  (I can ignore for now from the requirement to filter side-b by type-2)

Comment: first based on what criteria? there is no 'order' an a table to give you first unless you order by a column. You could for example use the key to order by. Do you have a column giving you an order?

Comment: Order by Connection ID. But it's not very important. The most important is that I need only one result for each item because I need to update its name with one value.

Comment: OK so next step is change the query to only select columns of interest: `IA.Key, IB.Name`. If I understand correctly you want to update each record identified by `IA.Key` with the value `IB.Name` but you now have duplicate `IA.Key` right? That's fine you can still write an update in this case and it will update with an arbitrary value

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid OK Thanks, I'll try tomorrow.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid Thanks!! you really helped and it worked. Do you want to post your comments as an answer?

Comment: I posted it - please indicate if this was not the correct answer (since you worked it out on your own - good work!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we build this up:

First step: select some data

```
select IA.* from Items IA
```

second step: join to connections

```
select IA.* from Items IA 
inner join Connections C 
on IA.Key = C.Side_A_Key
```

third step: join to connections on both sides

```
select IA.* from Items IA 
inner join Connections C 
on IA.Key = C.Side_A_Key 
inner join Items IB 
on IB.Key = C.Side_B_Key
```

fourth step: just select what we want:

```
select IA.Key, IB.Name 
from Items IA 
inner join Connections C 
on IA.Key = C.Side_A_Key 
inner join Items IB 
on IB.Key = C.Side_B_Key
```

fifth step: do an update:

```
update IA
set Name = IB.Name 
from Items IA 
inner join Connections C 
on IA.Key = C.Side_A_Key 
inner join Items IB 
on IB.Key = C.Side_B_Key
```